# why sticky position does not work in child div

Tags: html, css

i have multiple div in html page. when i try to stick  menu-bar it does not work and menu-bar is inside the other divs. here is the my code.

```css
#menubar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0
}

.content {
  /* to mimic content so we can have scroll */
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="bannerbox">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" height="100%" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div id="menubar">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="cityinfo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="content">

  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

where am doing mistake? I even tried many ways but it's not working.

i added dummy data in content div to make it scroll able up and down.

Comment: you need some content before and after the `div#menubar` element to see the effect of the `sticky` position.

Comment: @roshi pandy Use `position:fixed` instead of  `position:sticky` in your #menubar css

Comment: @ths as i mentioned above from sticky div there is image and below sticky div there is content upto 100 lines which i removed before asking question here

Comment: @Gaurav i want to use sticky not fixed as menu bar is not at the top but at the mid of page

Comment: @roshipandy I see, I added some content and your code wprks as expected.
@Gaurav `fixed` position is calculated relatively to the viewport thus the effect that the OP needs won't be acheived.

Comment: @ths what ? why its not working for me ? i added content of 500 lines in my content div. where u added ?

Comment: see [this pen](https://codepen.io/Thabet_Sakhraoui/pen/RqwLwy) then

Comment: @ths but i do not want to add <br> at the top because before menu bar there is just one image nothing else. i want all text in <div id="content">

Comment: `br` tags will act as any other kind of content, it's not ment to be used as is, just for the sake of the demo.

Comment: @ths actually i have no content before menu bar but just one image before menu bar so what should i do ?  any alternate or solution

Comment: post your full code that has relation with your issue and we'll see.

Comment: @ths this was my full code which i shared, just i did not added content in <div id="content"> content 1000 words </div>

Comment: add it so we gain more control over the issue.

Comment: @ths added now check it in pen

Comment: @roshipandy which pen ? Would you please add its link ?

Comment: @roshipandy very kind from you. At least i know what I can do. Hope you solve that small issue, sometime...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **[A stickily positioned element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)** is an element whose computed position value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" until meeting the opposite edge of its containing block.

With that in mind, we know we need our threshold to be met, meaning that `top:0` means when `#menubar` has 0 offset from top of it's containing block.

The containing block in our case is `#header` and it's height is defined by it's content, therefore the threshold is never met, because there's no overflow/scroll within it.

To see this more clearly we can apply some heights.

```css
#menubar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  /* when there's 10px space left between menubar and header */
  /* make it stick */
  top: 10px;
}

#header {
  border: 5px solid lime;
  height: 1000px;
}

.content {
  border: 5px solid orange;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="bannerbox">
      <img src="images/banner.png" height="100%" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div id="menubar">
      i'm stuck sticky
    </div>
    <div id="cityinfo">cityinfo</div>
  </div>

  <div id="content" class="content">
    header height is almost done, so the threshold will not be met very soon, this is what's hapening when the header has no overflow/scroll, menubar becomes sticky and goes back to normal almost instantly perhaps it never happens we don't know, it depends
    on how the user agant handles it.
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The fix would be to make header all together sticky or change how your html is laid out, i demonstrate either of them, because i don't know which is much more fitting for you, probably changing the markup isn't an option.